# Закрасит ячейки в календаре циклом JS

Tags: javascript

Есть 30 блоков .block стилизованные как календарь. 
Можно ли сделать красивый цикл в JS чтобы например каждый 6 и 7 блок (отвечающий за выходные) покрасить в другой цвет, типа такого:

```js
for (let i=0; i<30; i++) {
     ----<УСЛОВИЕ>---- {
       document.getElementsByClassName('block')[i].style.background = "green";
   }
  }
```

(При этом не применяя дополнительные классы для .block)

Comment: `if ((i % 5) === 0) { /* каждый шестой */`

Comment: @Danil а если месяц начинается не с понедельника?

Answer (score 1):

Знаю, что немного не по теме, но оставлю это здесь. Может, кому-нибудь пригодится.

```js
let oMonthName = document.querySelector('.month-name');
let oMonthGrid = document.querySelector('.month-grid');
// Дата
let oDateNow = new Date();
// Число
let nCurrDay = oDateNow.getDate();
// Количество дней
let nDayNumb = 32 - new Date(oDateNow.getFullYear(), oDateNow.getMonth(), 32).getDate();
// Название месяца
oMonthName.innerHTML = oDateNow.toLocaleString('ru-RU', {month: 'long'});
// Коррекция для начала месяца
oDateNow.setDate(nCurrDay + 2);
// Отступ в начале
oMonthGrid.innerHTML += `<div style="background:#ddd;height:1.6em;width:calc(2.5em * ${oDateNow.getDay()});"></div>`;
// Заполнение сетки
for (let i = 1; i <= nDayNumb; i++) {
  // Добавление анимации для текущего числа
  oMonthGrid.innerHTML += `<div class="block" style="${((i != nCurrDay)?'':'animation:pulse 1s ease-in-out infinite')};">${i}</div>`;
}
// Отступ в конце
oMonthGrid.innerHTML += `<div style="background:#ddd;height:1.6em;flex:1;"></div>`;
```

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

.month-wrap {
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
  font: bold 14px 'Tahoma';
}
.month-name {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 1.4em;
  padding: 0.3em;
  line-height: 1em;
  letter-spacing: 0.1em;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.month-grid {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  width: calc(2.5em * 7);
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #ffcccc 2.5em, #d1e9fa 2.5em, #d1e9fa 5em, transparent 5em);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.block {
  height: 1.6em;
  width: 2.5em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
  padding-right: 0.3em;
  text-align: right;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

@keyframes pulse { 50% { box-shadow: inset 0 0 25px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); } }
```

```html
<div class="month-wrap">
  <div class="month-name"></div>
  <div class="month-grid"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

можно без javascript

```css
.week
{
  width:300px;
  display:flex;
}

.block 
{
  flex: 1 auto;
  border: 1px solid black;  
}

.block:nth-child(7), .block:nth-child(6)
{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="week">
<div class="block">1</div>
<div class="block">2</div>
<div class="block">3</div>
<div class="block">4</div>
<div class="block">5</div>
<div class="block">6</div>
<div class="block">7</div>
</div>

<div class="week">
<div class="block">8</div>
<div class="block">9</div>
<div class="block">10</div>
<div class="block">11</div>
<div class="block">12</div>
<div class="block">13</div>
<div class="block">14</div>
</div>

<div class="week">
<div class="block">15</div>
<div class="block">16</div>
<div class="block">17</div>
<div class="block">18</div>
<div class="block">19</div>
<div class="block">20</div>
<div class="block">21</div>
</div>

<div class="week">
<div class="block">22</div>
<div class="block">23</div>
<div class="block">24</div>
<div class="block">25</div>
<div class="block">26</div>
<div class="block">27</div>
<div class="block">28</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Тут именно вопрос в условии для JS, есть ли на нём красивый способ написать такое условие.